# symmetric logarithmic plot (symlog)

Tags: gnuplot

How would you make a symlog plot in gnuplot?

[matplolib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/symlog_demo.html) has such a feature:

[image]

I'm thinking about some axis + tics manipulation or `multiplot` where on panel has reversed axis.

Finally, I need this for the `z` axis (`cbrange`) the show the residuals as an image.

Comment: What is the distance be between -1 and 0 and +1 (relative to 1 to 10, and -1 to -10) in this representation? Is the range between -1 and 0 and +1 linear? What would be the distance between 10 to 100 (-10 to -100)? This is not clear to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: All `symlog` axes are logarithmic also in the range -1 to 0 and 0 to 1. The last plot uses `linthreshy=0.015`, thus `-0.015==0==0.015`.

Comment: @Friedrich:  It is impossible for an axis to be logarithmic in a range that extends to 0. The matplotlib docs say "Since the values close to zero tend toward infinity, there is a need to have a range around zero that is linear. The parameter linthresh allows the user to specify the size of this range (-linthresh, linthresh)."

Comment: Hm, I could not find quickly a more detailed matplotlib doc. Anyway, just truncating at a threshold would be fine for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
symlog(x)  = (-1 < x && x < 1) ? x/10. \
           : (x < 0) ? -log(-x) - 0.1 \
           : log(x) + 0.1
invsymlog(x) = (-0.1 < x && x < 0.1) ? x*10. \
             : (x < 0) ? -exp(-(x+0.1)) \
             : exp(x-0.1)

set xlabel "Symlog axis"

set nonlinear x via symlog(x) inv invsymlog(x)
set xrange [-4*pi : 4*pi]
set sample 500

set xtics -10,1,10 nomirror
set xtics add ("//" 0)
set xtics font ",10"

plot x*cos(x)
```

[image]

The region between -1 and +1 is linear, the rest is log scale.